# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
           client.scp(jenkins_jobUrl, destinationpath_scriptFile, function(err) {

                    if (err)
                    throw err;
                    else
                    console.log("file uploaded");

                })
```

when this code gets executed first time after starting nodejs server it is putting file into remote sever and when it is executed for second time then it is throwing range error.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error second time? Try not to throw that.

Comment: My application is crashing beacause of stack size getting exceeded. I used setTimeout also thinking that it will clear stack but no result

Comment: Is the err object set the second time? Try to log that to the console.